# Angular CLI installation failure

Tags: angular-cli, angular2-cli

Installing Angular CLI (`angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16`) via `npm install -g angular-cli@latest` failed with the following error in `npm-debug.log`:

```
Error: The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
    at /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:125:32
    at /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:268:7
    at /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:142:5
    at /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:263:14
    at cb (/home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
    at /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:263:14
    at cb (/home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
    at /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:263:14
    at cb (/home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
    at /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:263:14
```

The install produced the following on the console for Node 3.3; and similarly failed on Node 4.6:

```
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
npm WARN engine angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16: wanted: {"node":">= 4.1.0"} (current: {"node":"3.3.1","npm":"2.14.3"})
npm WARN engine common-tags@1.3.1: wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"3.3.1","npm":"2.14.3"})
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency webpack@* included from html-webpack-plugin will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN engine html-minifier@3.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"3.3.1","npm":"2.14.3"})
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.

> execSync@1.0.2 install /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular2-template-loader/node_modules/codecov/node_modules/execSync
> node install.js

[execsync v1.0.2] Attempting to compile native extensions.
[execSync v1.0.2]
    Native code compile failed!!
npm WARN deprecated lodash.assign@4.2.0: This package is deprecated. Use Object.assign.
npm WARN engine selenium-webdriver@2.52.0: wanted: {"node":">= 4.2.x"} (current: {"node":"3.3.1","npm":"2.14.3"})
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package is discontinued. Use lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue                                       
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.14                                                                                           

> node-zopfli@2.0.1 install /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/node_modules/node-zopfli                                                                                                                                        
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build                                                                                                         

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/zopfli-v2.0.1-node-v45-linux-x64.tar.gz                          
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-zopfli@2.0.1 and node@3.3.1 (node-v45 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)  
make: Entering directory '/home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/node_modules/node-zopfli/build'                                                                                                                                   
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/src/zopfli-binding.o                                                                                       
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/src/png/zopflipng.o                                                                                        
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/blocksplitter.o                                                                           
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/cache.o                                                                                   
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/deflate.o                                                                                 
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/gzip_container.o                                                                          
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/hash.o                                                                                    
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/katajainen.o                                                                              
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/lz77.o                                                                                    
In file included from ../zopfli/src/zopfli/lz77.c:21:0:                                                                                            
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:38:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]                                   
 static int ZopfliGetDistExtraBits(int dist) {                                                                                                     
            ^                                                                                                                                      
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:61:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistExtraBitsValue’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]                              
 static int ZopfliGetDistExtraBitsValue(int dist) {                                                                                                
            ^                                                                                                                                      
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:138:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]                                
 static int ZopfliGetLengthExtraBits(int l) {                                                                                                      
            ^                                                                                                                                      
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:161:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthExtraBitsValue’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]                           
 static int ZopfliGetLengthExtraBitsValue(int l) {                                                                                                 
            ^                                                                                                                                      
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:222:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthSymbolExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthSymbolExtraBits(int s) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:231:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistSymbolExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistSymbolExtraBits(int s) {
            ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/squeeze.o
In file included from ../zopfli/src/zopfli/squeeze.c:28:0:
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:61:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistExtraBitsValue’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistExtraBitsValue(int dist) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:161:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthExtraBitsValue’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthExtraBitsValue(int l) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:222:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthSymbolExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthSymbolExtraBits(int s) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:231:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistSymbolExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistSymbolExtraBits(int s) {
            ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/tree.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/util.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/zlib_container.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/zopfli_lib.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopflipng/zopflipng_lib.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopflipng/lodepng/lodepng.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopflipng/lodepng/lodepng_util.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli.node
  COPY Release/zopfli.node
  COPY /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v45-linux-x64/zopfli.node
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
make: Leaving directory '/home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/node_modules/node-zopfli/build'
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@8.2.2: wanted: {"node":">=4.0"} (current: {"node":"3.3.1","npm":"2.14.3"})
-
> node-sass@3.10.1 install /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Start downloading binary at https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.10.1/linux-x64-45_binding.node
Binary downloaded and installed at /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-45/binding.node

> node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

"/home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-45/binding.node" exists. 
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
/home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/bin/ng -> /home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.7-42-desktop
npm ERR! argv "/home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/bin/iojs" "/home/jan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli@latest"
npm ERR! node v3.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer html-webpack-plugin@2.22.0 wants webpack@*
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-webpack@1.8.0 wants webpack@^1.1.0 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer sass-loader@3.2.3 wants webpack@^1.12.6 || ^2.1.0-beta
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer string-replace-loader@1.0.5 wants webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.0.0-beta || ^2.1.0-beta
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer webpack-dev-server@2.1.0-beta.3 wants webpack@^2.1.0-beta

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/jan/src/fm-repos/test/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: This is the original question https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2458#issuecomment-250960838

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade to Node 6 and re-install Angular CLI. With [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) maintaining and upgrading multiple version of Node is as simple as:

```
nvm install 6
nvm use 6
```

Angular CLI now installs and runs:

```
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
ng --version
  angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.16
  node: 6.6.0
  os: linux x64
ng foo
cd foo
ng serve
```

**Note 1:** The install failure says `npm WARN engine angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16: wanted: {"node":">= 4.1.0"}` but Node 4.6 fails similarly for me; so, use Node 6, instead. Node 5 work but there are disconcerting warnings during the install; see Note 2 below.

**Successful Node 6 install:**

```
npm -g install angular-cli@latest
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package is discontinued. Use lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated lodash.assign@4.2.0: This package is deprecated. Use Object.assign.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin/ng -> /home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng

> node-sass@3.10.1 install /home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Start downloading binary at https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.10.1/linux-x64-48_binding.node
Binary downloaded and installed at /home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-48/binding.node

> node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall /home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

"/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-48/binding.node" exists. 
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/lib
└─┬ angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16 
  ├── compression-webpack-plugin@0.3.2  (git://github.com/webpack/compression-webpack-plugin.git#7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54)
  ├─┬ css-loader@0.23.1
  │ └── postcss@5.2.4 
  ├─┬ ember-cli@2.5.0
  │ ├─┬ bower-config@1.4.0
  │ │ └─┬ osenv@0.1.3
  │ │   └── os-homedir@1.0.2 
  │ ├─┬ broccoli-babel-transpiler@5.6.1
  │ │ └─┬ babel-core@5.8.38
  │ │   └─┬ is-integer@1.0.6
  │ │     └── is-finite@1.0.2 
  │ ├─┬ configstore@2.1.0
  │ │ └── os-tmpdir@1.0.2 
  │ └─┬ inquirer@0.12.0
  │   └─┬ readline2@1.0.1
  │     └─┬ code-point-at@1.0.1 
  │       └── number-is-nan@1.0.1 
  ├─┬ fs-extra@0.30.0
  │ └── path-is-absolute@1.0.1 
  └─┬ node-sass@3.10.1 
    └─┬ meow@3.7.0
      └─┬ loud-rejection@1.6.0
        └─┬ currently-unhandled@0.4.1
          └── array-find-index@1.0.2 

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /angular-cli/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
jan@linux-zd16:~/src/fm-repos/test> 
jan@linux-zd16:~/src/fm-repos/test>
```

**Note 2:** If you choose Node 5, the console is littered with apparently benign warnings for `node-zopfli@2.0.1` -- see below. These are warnings are fixed with Node 6...

**Successful Node 5 install console:**

```
jan@linux-zd16:~/src/fm-repos/test> nvm use 5
Now using node v5.12.0 (npm v3.8.6)
jan@linux-zd16:~/src/fm-repos/test> npm cache clear
jan@linux-zd16:~/src/fm-repos/test> npm install -g angular-cli@latest
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package is discontinued. Use lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated lodash.assign@4.2.0: This package is deprecated. Use Object.assign.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/bin/ng -> /home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng

> execSync@1.0.2 install /home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/execSync
> node install.js

[execsync v1.0.2] Attempting to compile native extensions.
[execSync v1.0.2]
    Native code compile failed!!

> node-zopfli@2.0.1 install /home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-zopfli
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/zopfli-v2.0.1-node-v47-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-zopfli@2.0.1 and node@5.12.0 (node-v47 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
make: Entering directory '/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-zopfli/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/src/zopfli-binding.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/src/png/zopflipng.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/blocksplitter.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/cache.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/deflate.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/gzip_container.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/hash.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/katajainen.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/lz77.o
In file included from ../zopfli/src/zopfli/lz77.c:21:0:
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:38:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistExtraBits(int dist) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:61:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistExtraBitsValue’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistExtraBitsValue(int dist) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:138:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthExtraBits(int l) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:161:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthExtraBitsValue’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthExtraBitsValue(int l) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:222:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthSymbolExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthSymbolExtraBits(int s) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:231:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistSymbolExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistSymbolExtraBits(int s) {
            ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/squeeze.o
In file included from ../zopfli/src/zopfli/squeeze.c:28:0:
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:61:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistExtraBitsValue’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistExtraBitsValue(int dist) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:161:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthExtraBitsValue’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthExtraBitsValue(int l) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:222:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthSymbolExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthSymbolExtraBits(int s) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:231:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistSymbolExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistSymbolExtraBits(int s) {
            ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/tree.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/util.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/zlib_container.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/zopfli_lib.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopflipng/zopflipng_lib.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopflipng/lodepng/lodepng.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopflipng/lodepng/lodepng_util.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli.node
  COPY Release/zopfli.node
  COPY /home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v47-linux-x64/zopfli.node
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
make: Leaving directory '/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-zopfli/build'

> node-sass@3.10.1 install /home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Start downloading binary at https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.10.1/linux-x64-47_binding.node
Binary downloaded and installed at /home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-47/binding.node

> node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall /home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

"/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-47/binding.node" exists. 
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.


npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /angular-cli/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
```